# What exactly is Azure Pipelines agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

After reading the very short [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) about the azure pipeline agent, I am getting very confused.

1. What exactly is an azure pipeline agent?
2. What is an agent job?
3. What's the relationship between agent and VM?
4. What's the relationship between agent job and VM? For each agent， one VM will be temporally assigned to it and will be back to the pool after the agent job finished?
5. If 2 different agent jobs run by 2 agents need the same running environment and the VM is agent job dependent. How should I retain the first agent job's running environment after it's finished running? Recreated again?
6. If each agent needs a VM, why create this concept? why not just directly use the VM or container?

Answer (score 0):

1. Pipeline agent is machine where your build is performed. An agent is installable software that runs one job at a time.
2. Agent job is a set of steps which is recognized as execution boundary. Each job runs on an agent. All of the steps run together on the same agent.
3. From that perspective you can distinguish two kind of jobs - the onces installed on VM and onces instaled on container.
4. Agent job runs on agent which can be installed on VM. VM's are not assigned. Agents are assigned. There is agent pool, not VM pool.
5. I don't understand this one. Agents after finishing their job are going back to pool.
6. You may have more agents on on VM for instance one agents is installed on VM and few others as containers.

Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops). You will find explanation for these concepts.

[image: Key concepts for new Azure Pipelines users]

Comment: Can the running environment that needs to run a job be treated as part of the agent?

Comment: IMHO yes, because of capabilities.

Every self-hosted agent has a set of capabilities that indicate what it can do. Capabilities are name-value pairs that are either automatically discovered by the agent software, in which case they are called system capabilities, or those that you define, in which case they are called user capabilities.